# How to get Firebase Token on a certain Event

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have added `Firebase Notification` in my project, now when i launch the application it Hit the `Firebase server` and gets the `Token`. I want it to hold the request, and hit the firebase server on an event.

This is what i have done, I have not created any instance of Firebase, It gets called on its own.

```
<service android:name=".FirebaseCloudMessaging.FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


    <service android:name=".FirebaseCloudMessaging.FirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**FirebaseInstanceIDService  Class**

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private final String SHARD_PREF = "com.tixsee.mavs.gcmcloudmessaging";
    private final String GCM_TOKEN = "gcmtoken";
    private final String TAG = FirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();
    String token;
    private Context mContext;
    public FirebaseInstanceIDService() {

    }

 @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        SharedPreferences appPrefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARD_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        token = appPrefs.getString(GCM_TOKEN, "");
        if (token.isEmpty()) {

            token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            sendTokenToService(token);
            Log.d(TAG, "New Token Created" + token);

            SharedPreferences notificationPreference = getSharedPreferences(SHARD_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor notificationPrefsEditor = notificationPreference.edit();
            notificationPrefsEditor.putString("NOTIFICATION_ENABLED", "true");
            notificationPrefsEditor.apply();
}
```

Kindly guide me how to hold Firebase request, and trigger it on any certain event.

Comment: using this method FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()

Comment: Thanks, but it will still send the token request at the launch of application, how to stop that?

Comment: onTokenRefresh() would be called if the token for your application has been updated by the Instance ID service. The main reason for onTokenRefresh() being called is to allow you to update your app server with the new token so it can send messages to your app.

So if you want to stop updating id every time on dont call FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() form you app anywhere instead public void onTokenRefresh()

Comment: Why you want to hold the token generation ? Please explain.

Comment: @SangeetSuresh . I want it to send to the server once user accepts to receive notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store a flag for user accepts notification in Shared Preference

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("notification", true);
editor.commit();
```

Then check the flag in onTokenRefresh()

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean value = sharedPref.getBoolean("notification", false);

if(value)
   {
     \\ Send to token(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()) to server 
  }
```

If the flag is set then send token to server.

Also put if onTokenRefresh is called automatically before user accepts screen. Then check `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` is null or not.

```
if(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()!=null)
{
 \\ Send to token(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()) to server 
}
```

If its not null then send that token to server.

Hope this will solve your question.